# Printing a Python dictionary item row by row (Sequentially) in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary sdict with 4 key:value pairs. I want to print two of it's items (Source_columns and Target_columns) row by row in a CSV file. 
The dictionary sdict:

```
{'Target_Table': 'scott  .  employees',
 'Target_Columns': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name  email  phone_number  JOB_DATE  job_id  salary  commission_pct  manager_id  department_id',
 'Source_Columns': 'emp_id    last_name    first_name    email    phone_number    JOB_DATE    job_id    salary    commission_pct    manager_id    department_id',
 'Source_Table': 'scott  .  employee',
 'where_expr': 'emp_id  =  old_emp_id'}
```

I tried simple ways like using split() method but all of them can just split the values in different lines in normal output not happening in CSV.
If I add .replace(" ","\n") then all the content after space is getting removed.
Below is my working code. What do I add in it so that I can get my output something like this in CSV file: (I just wrote down 2 column's content..)

```
Source Table     Target Columns

emp_tab          empp_id
                 last_name 
                 first_name
                 email 
                 phone_number 
                 JOB_DATE  ...
```

What I'm getting right now is something like this:

```
Target_Columns
empp_id  last_name  first_name  email  phone_number  JOB_DATE  job_id  salary  commission_pct  manager_id  department_id
```

```
with open("proc.txt", 'r') as file:   
    if re.search(r'select|SELECT', file.read()):
        selr = select_stmt.parseString(open('proc.txt').read());
        sd=selr.asDict()
        sdict={k: str(v).strip("[]").replace("'", "").replace(","," ").replace("["," ").replace("]"," ") for k, v in sd.items()}

with open('procfile11.csv', 'w') as f: 
    fieldnames = ["Source_Table","Source_Columns","Target_Table","Target_Columns"]
    fieldnames = sorted(set(sd.keys()).union(*[sdict]))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore') 
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(sdict)
```

Comment: you just want to print the values for `Source_columns` and `Target_columns` sequentially in the csv right?

Comment: Yes along with rest of the items